# How to resolve "Uncaught typeError: cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')" in React

Tags: reactjs

Getting "Uncaught typeError: cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList');
I want to access my navigation bar in order to make it appear and disappear on window scroll by adding and removing a class I created in CSS.
The code works for sometime and then stop. When I check the console I get the above Error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP0eN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Lets first take a look at your original code which has a few areas that could be improved:

1. Direct querying of DOM elements via `document.querySelector('.float_nav');`
2. Recreation of scroll event listener on every render via `window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {...});`
3. Missing clean up of scroll event listener.
4. Missing clean up of `setTimeout`.

Original Code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import '.floating_nav.css';
import { AiOutlineHome, AiOutlineUser } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { BiBook, BiMessageSquareDetail } from 'react-icons/bi';
import { RiServiceLine } from 'react-icons/ri';

const FloatingNav = () => {
    // On mount this will not be able to find the div because it has not yet been rendered.
    //
    // On subsequent renders this will work, but it is frowned upon as it ignore the react
    // component lifecycle.
    //
    // As a result of how closures work, and the fact that you never remove the scroll 
    // listener, the initial scroll listener will always be referencing undefined.
    const float_nav = document.querySelector('.float_nav');

    // This will add an event listener on mount and every rerender.
    //
    // This is never cleaned up, so if the component is removed this event handler
    // will continue to fire, throw errors and hold references to DOM elements that
    // may interfere with GC.
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        float_nav.classList.add('show');

        setTimeout(() => {
            float_nav.classList.remove('show');
        }, 5000);
    });

    const [ activeNav, setActiveNav ] = useState('#header');

    return (
        <div
            className="float_nav"
        >
            <a
                href="#header"
                onClick={() => setActiveNav('#header')}
                className={activeNav === '#header' ? 'active' : ''}
            >
                <AiOutlineHome />
            </a>
            <a
                href="#about"
                onClick={() => setActiveNav('#about')}
                className={activeNav === '#about' ? 'active' : ''}
            >
                <AiOutlineUser />
            </a>
            <a
                href="#portfolio"
                onClick={() => setActiveNav('#portfolio')}
                className={activeNav === '#portfolio' ? 'active' : ''}
            >
                <BiBook />
            </a>
            <a
                href="#services"
                onClick={() => setActiveNav('#services')}
                className={activeNav === '#services' ? 'active' : ''}
            >
                <RiServiceLine />
            </a>
            <a
                href="#contact"
                onClick={() => setActiveNav('#contact')}
                className={activeNav === '#contact' ? 'active' : ''}
            >
                <BiMessageSquareDetail />
            </a>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I would suggest the following fixes:

1. Use a `useRef` to get a reference to the required DOM element.
2. Use a `useEffect` to ensure the event listener is only created as required.
3. Use the return function of the same `useEffect` to remove the event listener when the component is unmounted.
4. Use the return function of the same `useEffect` (again?!) to clear the possible running `setTimeout` when the component is unmounted.

Suggested Code:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import '.floating_nav.css';
import { AiOutlineHome, AiOutlineUser } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { BiBook, BiMessageSquareDetail } from 'react-icons/bi';
import { RiServiceLine } from 'react-icons/ri';

const FloatingNav = () => {
    // Use a ref to get a reference to the div element.
    //
    // This will not have a value until the div is rendered (added to the DOM).
    const divRef = useRef();

    // Use a useEffect to only register the event handler once.
    //
    // By the time the useEffect is run the ref should contain a reference
    // to the div.
    useEffect(() => {
        // Create a variable to store the timer id.
        let timerId = undefined;

        // Create the event handler, need a reference to later
        // remove the listener.
        const eventHandler =  () => {
            // Use the ref to get a reference to the DOM Element.
            //
            // Use the conditional operator (?) to ensure no error is thrown if the 
            // handler is triggered during clean up before the listener is 
            // removed.
            divRef.current?.classList.add('show');
    
            // Clear the timer if it exists.
            //
            // This will stop UI wierdness if you trigger the handler 
            // multiple times within a 5000ms period.
            timerId && clearTimeout(timerId);

            // Store id of setTimeout so that it can be cleaned up later.
            timerId = setTimeout(() => {
                divRef.current?.classList.remove('show');
            }, 5000);
        };

        // Add the event listener.
        window.addEventListener('scroll', eventHandler);

        // Clean up that will be run on unmount / before the useEffect is rerun.
        //
        // This useEffect will only run on mount and clean up on unmount, this
        // is due to the fact that the dependency array value [divRef] only
        // contians divRef which is a static reference for the life of the 
        // component.
        return () => {
            // Clear the timer if it exists.
            //
            // This will stop the timeout triggering after the component
            // is unmounted.
            timerId && clearTimeout(timerId);

            // Remove the event listener.
            //
            // This will stop the event listener triggering after the
            // component is unmounted.
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', eventHandler)
        };
    }, [divRef])

    const [ activeNav, setActiveNav ] = useState('#header');

    // Add ref to div.
    return (
        <div
            ref={divRef}
            className="float_nav"
        >
            <a
                href="#header"
                onClick={() => setActiveNav('#header')}
                className={activeNav === '#header' ? 'active' : ''}
            >
                <AiOutlineHome />
            </a>
            <a
                href="#about"
                onClick={() => setActiveNav('#about')}
                className={activeNav === '#about' ? 'active' : ''}
            >
                <AiOutlineUser />
            </a>
            <a
                href="#portfolio"
                onClick={() => setActiveNav('#portfolio')}
                className={activeNav === '#portfolio' ? 'active' : ''}
            >
                <BiBook />
            </a>
            <a
                href="#services"
                onClick={() => setActiveNav('#services')}
                className={activeNav === '#services' ? 'active' : ''}
            >
                <RiServiceLine />
            </a>
            <a
                href="#contact"
                onClick={() => setActiveNav('#contact')}
                className={activeNav === '#contact' ? 'active' : ''}
            >
                <BiMessageSquareDetail />
            </a>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I would also suggest that you post code snippets instead of pictures in the future to make it easier for people to answer with modified snippets.